# Delete specific word at the beginning

Tags: sql, sql-server

in my table within some columns i got strings which starting always with `/PicsDB`

like this below:

```
/PicsDB/Something 2015/Some thing bla/Some thing other/img34234.jpg
```

what i want to achieve is to for each row delete starting string `/PicsDB`

so using above string the final result should be:

```
/Something 2015/Some thing bla/Some thing other/img34234.jpg
```

How to achieve that?

Can i just simply do ? :

```
UPDATE my_table SET path = replace(path, '/PicsDB', '');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use substring:

```
UPDATE my_table SET path = substring(path, 8, 9999);
where path like '/PicsDB%'
```

Comment: In your case most likely, but it will replace that string also from the middle of the path if it happens to exist